# Mac OS X linker error in Qt; CoreGraphics & CGWindowListCreate

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, macos, objective-c++

Here is my .mm file

```
#include "windowmanagerutils.h"

#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
#import </System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGWindow.h>

QRect WindowManagerUtils::getWindowRect(WId windowId)
{
    CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
    return QRect();
}

QRect WindowManagerUtils::getClientRect(WId windowId)
{
    return QRect();
}

QString WindowManagerUtils::getWindowText(WId windowId)
{
    return QString();
}

WId WindowManagerUtils::rootWindow()
{
    QApplication::desktop()->winId();
}

WId WindowManagerUtils::windowFromPoint(const QPoint &p, WId parent, bool(*filterFunction)(WId))
{
    return NULL;
}

void WindowManagerUtils::setTopMostCarbon(const QWidget *const window, bool topMost)
{
    if (!window)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Find a Cocoa equivalent for this Carbon function
    // [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/Current/Carbon")]
    // OSStatus ret = HIViewSetZOrder(this->winId(), kHIViewZOrderAbove, NULL);
}
#endif
```

The linker is telling me "_CGWindowListCreate" is undefined. What libraries must I link to? Apple's documentation is not very helpful on telling what to include or link to, like MSDN is. Also I couldn't just do `#import <CGWindow.h>`, I had to specify the absolute path to it... any way around that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [CGWindowListCreate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) function is part of the [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Introduction.html). The corresponding framework is `ApplicationServices` which is located under `/System/Library/Frameworks/`.

So, you can just include `<ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>` at the top of the file and link with the `-framework ApplicationServices`option.

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I was able to link to ApplicationServices by placing: `mac:LIBS += -framework ApplicationServices` in my .pro file and `#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>` in my .mm file.

Comment: For GCC compiler this is how I linked it. g++ -framework ApplicationServices test.cpp -o test